# ruby aws sdk v2 how to get the value of snapshot tag

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

The result of `p snapshot.tags` is:

```
[#<struct Aws::EC2::Types::Tag key="snapshot_expire", value="2016-09-23 08:30:12 +0000">]
```

How do I get only the value of Tag Key `snapshot_expire` without the hour:sec:min (2016-09-23) ?

This is my code:

```
resp = ec2.describe_snapshots(owner_ids:['1234']) #.each do |snapshot|
resp.snapshots.each do |snapshot|
  p snapshot.snapshot_id
  p snapshot.tags
end
```

I know that the regular aws cli tool has this option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/EC2/Client.html#describe_snapshots-instance_method

The 'snapshots' are returned as objects. You can get the specific snapshot data from the object using methods; see the documentation above. The snapshot ID is available by calling snapshot.snapshot_id. Tags are snapshot.tags.

```
require 'aws-sdk'
require 'date'
ec2 = Aws::EC2::Client.new(region: 'us-east-1')

snapshot_response = ec2.describe_snapshots(owner_ids:['xxx'])
snapshot_response.snapshots.each do |snapshot|
  tagkeyexpire = snapshot.tags.select{|tag| tag.key == 'snapshot_expire'}
  snapid = snapshot.snapshot_id
  expiredate = Date.parse(tagkeyexpire[0].value) unless tagkeyexpire == []
  puts "#{snapid} : #{expiredate}"
end
```

Output looks like

```
snap-01234567 : 2016-09-30
```

Comment: thanks @Nathan, when I tried to print the snapshots ids `puts snapshot.snapshot_id` I got an error `method_missing': undefined method `snapshot_id' for #<Seahorse::Client::Response:0x00000002bb9340> (NoMethodError)`
`

Comment: also another error with your soultion :/  `include?': undefined method each' for #<struct Aws::EC2::Types::Tag key="GROUP", value="PROD"> (NoMethodError)`

Comment: Updated code block; I just tested this in IRB and it runs fine. I get back an empty set [] for the tags since I don't have snapshot_expire as a tag anywhere but it runs and prints out nicely.

Comment: nice, thanks~ the result of `tagkeyexpire` is `[#<struct Aws::EC2::Types::Tag key="snapshot_expire", value="2016-09-30 04:30:11 +0000">]`, is there a way to take only the date ? `2016-09-30`, to do something with ruby.

Comment: or maybe is it possible to get only the value of the `tag.key`  `snapshot_expire` ?

Comment: Updated, see above. :)

Comment: do you know maybe why when I tried to delete snapshot with `snapshot.delete` or `snapshot.delete_snapshot` , I got an error `undefined method delete_snapshot' for #<Aws::EC2::Types::Snapshot:0x00000001ab7c18> (NoMethodError)` or `undefined method delete' for #<Aws::EC2::Types::Snapshot:0x00000001d3ee28> (NoMethodError)`

Comment: The snapshot object is just the response. You can feed the snap ID into the ec2.delete_snapshot call and that will do it (looks like you found that already). :)